# Modifying records in a linked list C++

Tags: c++, linked-list

Okay so what I want to happen is the program will ask me to input the id of the tutor that I want to modify, after that let's say in this case I want to modify the address and phone number of the tutor. I'm not exactly sure how to approach this so any help would be appreciated!Please guide me to the right direction, thanks!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <stdlib.h>

using namespace std;



//Has functions accepts input & prints output in date format
class date {

public:
    int day, month, year;
    char seperator = '/';
    void enter() {
        cin >> day >> seperator >> month >> seperator >> year;
    }
    void display() {
        cout << day << seperator << month << seperator << year;
    }
    void reset() {
        day = 0;
        month = 0;
        year = 0;
    }
};

//Declaring tutor structure of Variables Globally (up to 100 records)
struct tutor {
    tutor* back;
    int tutorID;
    string tutorName;
    date dateJoined;
    date dateTerminate;
    float hourlyRate;
    string phoneNum;
    string address;
    int tCentreCode;
    string tCentreName;
    string tCentreLocation;
    int subjectCode;
    string subjectName;
    int rating;
    tutor* next;
}*list, *newnode, *temp, *previous, *tail;

void generateSample() {

    list = NULL;

    newnode = new tutor;
    newnode->tutorID = 1;
    newnode->tutorName = "Yow Tew Thung";
    newnode->address = "2, Jln 1/3, Bandar Sri Selamat";
    newnode->phoneNum = "0121231542";
    newnode->dateJoined.day = 15;  newnode->dateJoined.month = 01; newnode->dateJoined.year = 2017;
    newnode->dateTerminate.day = 10; newnode->dateTerminate.month = 11; newnode->dateTerminate.year = 2019;
    newnode->tCentreCode = 4;
    newnode->tCentreName = "eXcel Bukit Bintang 1";
    newnode->tCentreLocation = "Bukit Bintang";
    newnode->subjectCode = 4;
    newnode->subjectName = "History";
    newnode->rating = 5;
    newnode->hourlyRate = 45;

    list = tail = newnode;


    newnode = new tutor;
    newnode->tutorID = 2;
    newnode->tutorName = "Syed Hasif";
    newnode->address = "17, Jln Zainal Abidin 4, Suria";
    newnode->phoneNum = "0189056841";
    newnode->dateJoined.day = 05;  newnode->dateJoined.month = 05; newnode->dateJoined.year = 2019;
    newnode->dateTerminate.day = 02; newnode->dateTerminate.month = 11; newnode->dateTerminate.year = 2020;
    newnode->tCentreCode = 1;
    newnode->tCentreName = "eXcel Bukit Jalil 1";
    newnode->tCentreLocation = "Bukit Jalil";
    newnode->subjectCode = 2;
    newnode->subjectName = "Bahasa Melayu";
    newnode->rating = 3;
    newnode->hourlyRate = 45;

    newnode->back = tail;
    tail->next = newnode;
    tail = newnode;

    newnode = new tutor;
    newnode->tutorID = 3;
    newnode->tutorName = "Chong Kun Li";
    newnode->address = "34, Jalan 1/3Y, PJU8, Kiara";
    newnode->phoneNum = "0189343221";
    newnode->dateJoined.day = 05;  newnode->dateJoined.month = 05; newnode->dateJoined.year = 2019;
    newnode->dateTerminate.day = 02; newnode->dateTerminate.month = 11; newnode->dateTerminate.year = 2020;
    newnode->tCentreCode = 2;
    newnode->tCentreName = "eXcel Subang Jaya 1";
    newnode->tCentreLocation = "Subang Jaya";
    newnode->subjectCode = 3;
    newnode->subjectName = "Mathematics";
    newnode->rating = 3;
    newnode->hourlyRate = 49;

    newnode->back = tail;
    tail->next = newnode;
    tail = newnode;

    newnode = new tutor;
    newnode->tutorID = 4;
    newnode->tutorName = "Sangeta Mahad";
    newnode->address = "9, Jln 17J, Medan Keramat";
    newnode->phoneNum = "0163457985";
    newnode->dateJoined.day = 05;  newnode->dateJoined.month = 05; newnode->dateJoined.year = 2019;
    newnode->dateTerminate.day = 02; newnode->dateTerminate.month = 11; newnode->dateTerminate.year = 2020;
    newnode->tCentreCode = 3;
    newnode->tCentreName = "eXcel Subang Jaya 2";
    newnode->tCentreLocation = "Subang Jaya";
    newnode->subjectCode = 3;
    newnode->subjectName = "Mathematics";
    newnode->rating = 1;
    newnode->hourlyRate = 40;

    newnode->back = tail;
    tail->next = newnode;
    tail = newnode;

    system("PAUSE");
    system("cls");
}
```

Comment: Separate the linked list from the application logic. That way you can implement and test the linked list alone. You'll find that much, much easier.

Comment: Think about how you would do this by hand. Draw pictures if it helps.

Comment: You have the `id`, so just start at the beginning of your list and iterate over the nodes until you locate the `id` and then update the values of `address` and `phone number`.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest writing a `tutor * findTutorByName(const std::string &)` function that takes a tutor's name as an argument, and then iterates over the linked list looking for a node whose `tutorName` field matches that name, and if it finds such a node, it returns a pointer to that node.  If it doesn't find such a node, it should return NULL.

Once you've don't that, the remainder of the problem is just a matter of calling `tutor * t = findTutorByName(the_name_i_want)`, and if `t` isn't a NULL pointer, setting fields in `t` (e.g. `t->phoneNum = "12345678";`)

(Side note:  the posted code has four repetitions of the same 14-line code sequence.  Any time you notice multiple repetitions of near-identical code like that, take that as a signal that there is an opportunity to write a function to unify that code into a single location, and then replace the *N* multiple instances of repeated code with calls to that function instead.  It will save you lots of pain in the long run, since you'll only have to fix bugs and make changes in one place instead of *N* places)

Answer (score 0):

Point a tutur pointer to the start on the tutor list and check the id of the node. If the node is the correct id then modify the pointer, if not move to the next item.

Or create map from ids to tutor pointer with the id as the key for the map.